# Python3 How do I get assertEqual to print all the contextual info?

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I'm using unittest.TestCase in Python 3 and needing more info printed when assertEqual finds a problem.

My test function includes the statement:

```
self.assertEqual(result, exp_result, "Test_svg_glyph_scale test #" + str(test_num))
```

Upon finding an error, it's supposed to print `result` and `exp_result` and the string that's in the call to `assertEqual`. however, it's truncating the `__repr__` outputs for `result` and `exp_result`:

```
FAIL: test_scale (__main__.Test_svg_glyph)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "svg_glyph_test.py", line 322, in test_scale
    self.assertEqual(result, exp_result, "Test_svg_glyph_scale test #" + str(test_num))
AssertionError: glyph[15 chars]5000,-0.5000) 
       l(0.0000,1.0000) 
      [75 chars]   ]) != glyph[15 chars]5000,0.5000) 
       l(0.0000,1.0000) 
       [74 chars]   ]) : Test_svg_glyph_scale test #1
```

It's those [15 chars] and [75 chars] that I would like to see so I know exactly what's being returned and expected (okay, I know this one) and to be able to compare them easily.

`maxDiff` seems to apply to only string comparisons. I am trying to compare two structures.

Is there a setting I can change to get all the characters printed?

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to disable this very strange Python 3-behaviour. Seems the only way is to fix it is to monkey-patch the unittest.util module directly:

```
unittest.util._MAX_LENGTH = 160  # Default is 80, so this doubles it
```

After this all "[25 chars]" strings where gone, and I could read the output of my test failures again.

(For reference, the affected code [util.py is on GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/unittest/util.py))

Answer (score 0):

As of python 3.2 you can set `self.maxDiff = None` (or a larger value) to print out more details

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.maxDiff